# how to expand list into pattern in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a list like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I am pulling those numbers into another spreadsheet, using vlookup.

I want to create a new list or pattern, that looks like this:

```
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
.. etc
```

How can I do that easily (my first list has 300 items, so dont want to do by hand)

Thanks!

Comment: update: the pattern always stays the same

Comment: + a followup would be, could I do the same while transposing. For example, if in my original rows I have some Weight figures, ie 10, 20 ,30  .... could those be transposed as well? Probably a different type of lookup I guess.

Comment: You mean the number of repetitions of each value is fixed at 5? Or do you wish this to be a variable?

Comment: it would always be the same number of repetitions, IE, converting 1 SKU number into 5 - then going on to the next

Comment: And, just as in your example, there are never any empty cells in between your data that would require skipping in the solution, i.e. 1 [blank] 2 3 4 is not a possibility for your original range?

Comment: no.. always the same.. end results should turn 1,2,3 (rows) into: 1-a, 1-b, 1-c, 1-d, 2-a, 2-b, 2-c, 2-d, etc (hard to read, but hope it makes sense)

Comment: for now, I did do the copy paste - so I have my workaround, but its an interesting problem for me, and if a automated solution exists, its great to have it in my toolbox :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the Scheme:

[image]

use the formulas:

```
C2 -> =A2
C3 -> =INDEX(A:A;ROUNDDOWN((ROW(G1)/$B$2)+2;0))    ' And Autocomplete
D2 -> =IF((ROUNDUP(ROW(G1)/($B$2+$B$4);0))-(ROUNDDOWN((ROW(G1)/($B$2+$B$4))+($B$4)/$B$2-$B$4/10;0))=1;INDEX(A:A;ROUNDDOWN((ROW(G1)/($B$2+$B$4))+2;0));"")    ' And Autocomplete
```

The **C** column it's relevant to repeat without blanks, the column **D** it's relevant to the repeat with blanks.
In the cells **B2** put the number of repetition and in the cell **B4** put the blanks cells.
If you have more that one column to copy use the same code for every column...
If you need to have only values, at the end copy and paste with value ...
**Warning:** The formula in column D work with low number of blanks and Repeat... Eventually you need to recalibrate.

Comment: genius! It works - many thanks. 

One small bug, I cannot work out the C1>A2 part. For some reason, the very first number it only repeats 4 times - the rest is OK. But I will fix that myself I'm sure!

Thanks again... happy to have this on file :)

Comment: Correct ... Infact the reason for the first Cell C2 = A2 it's the reason for this ...

Comment: got it. You've been a great help. Have a good weekend!! I'm gonna play with Excel for 6 hours now :)